# EEPROM as alternative for FLASH STorage for Booting Pico 2040

Tags: pi-pico, eeprom

I am reaching out to gain more insights on using EEPROM via SPI for booting the RP2040 Pico. Kindly guide with your experience of using or not using it, we have EEPROM in our inventory & would like to check if we can use the same for RP2040 Pico.
I have browsed through the hardware design manual of the Pico & did not find anything explictly helpful yet, your insights shall be valuable.

Comment: Pico is a microcontroller not a computer. It has no OS; You don't "boot" it.

Comment: I mean instead of using FLASH to source the firmware, can we use EEPROM? Do you have any insights on this use case?

Comment: I recently came across this page https://vanhunteradams.com/Pico/Bootloader/Boot_sequence.html describing the boot process of the RP2040. This might be helpful.